# Pipeline fails due to `hijack: Backend error`

Tags: concourse

I'm following [Stark & Wayne](https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial/tree/master/10_job_inputs) tutorial and got into a problem:

Pipeline fails with

```
hijack: Backend error: Exit status: 500, message {"Type":"","Message": "
runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:247:
starting container process caused \"exec format error\"\n","Handle":""}
```

I have one `git` resource and one job with one task:

```
- task: test
  file: resource-ci/ci/test.yml
```

test.yml file:

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: busybox
    tag: latest

inputs:
- name: resource-tool

run:
  path: resource-tool/scripts/deploy.sh
```

`deploy.sh` is simple dummy file with one `echo` command

```
echo [+] Testing in the process ...
```

So what could it be?

Comment: yes is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029181/how-run-concourse-task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the shell it's trying to invoke in your script is unavailable on the container running your task.

Busybox doesn't come with bash, it only comes with `/bin/sh`, check the shebang in `deploy.sh`, making sure it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# rest of script
```

Comment: also chmod +x deploy.sh

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error when I forgot to add a `!` at the top of my pipelines shell script:

```
#/bin/bash
# rest of script
```