# How come .sh shell scripts work in Concourse tutorial but NOT in my actual codebase?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, yaml, concourse

Very much a newbie to CI system setup, so please be gentle :)

I'm following a [Stark And Wayne tutorial](https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial/blob/master/03_task_scripts/task_show_uname.yml) & trying to get a Concourse CI task yml to run a shell script that it finds via the input folder:

task.yml

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: my-input-folder

run:
  path: ./my-input-folder/my-shell-script.sh
```

So when i run:

`fly --target team-name execute --config task.yml -i my-input-folder=my-input-folder`

It should go into that folder, action `my-shell-script.sh` and echo the `this is working` that's in there.

Instead i get:

```
hijack: Backend error: Exit status: 500, message: {"Type":"","Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:264: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"./__tests__/this-is-my-shell-script.sh\\\": permission denied\"\n","Handle":""}
```

I get this is *something* to do with the docker/busybox image, [from this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816539/pipeline-fails-due-to-hijack-backend-error).

But...

a) why does it work with the same `.sh` extension and `busybox` image on their tutorial? (but then *not* when i use it on my actual project?)

b) how can i resolve this so that my project is running shell scripts? Which docker image would work?

Answer (score 4):

I found out through colleagues this error was due to:

a) needing to `chmod +x folder/name-of-file.sh` so it's an executable file.

and

b) Adding in the `#!/bin/sh` to the beginning of my `.sh` file (as i'm using oh-my-zsh). Though i gather if i were using bash, this would be `#!/bin/bash`.

Now the shell script links fine.

Answer (score 1):

I changed image to ubuntu image and it worked, but alpine is not working too. Ubuntu is more fat and has more initial sh commands. Lightweight (alpine, busybox) has less sh commands.

```
source: {repository: ubuntu}
```

Answer (score 0):

a) since it was created in there git it runs fine as permission is set in there files. when you modify it or created a new file it does not work as permission is changed. I assume that you are using a windows machine.

b) the solution is to change the git index permission git update-index --chmod=+x /path/to/file. If you change only the files local permission it might work since you are trying to run a one-off task but will give you complications once you start using concourse git resource that you will encounter further down the tutorial

refer https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/2161