# How to run a concourse task

Tags: message, backend, status

I am new in the community, I am working with concourse and I have the next issue running a yml file in terminal using fly:

```
command $: sudo fly -t ci execute -c task.yml
```

I get the following error:

> initializing Backend error: Exit status: 500, message:
>   {"Type":"","Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\"/root\") set in config.json failed: permission denied\"\n","Handle":"","ProcessID":""}

Please help if anyone can help me!

Comment: please show content of your yaml file

Comment: yml file: ---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

run:
  path: echo
  args: [hello world] .

Comment: I'm running only hello world from concourse, I haven't  any problem deploying the web environment, I am using ubuntu 16.04  and I'm following the next tutorial:  https://concoursetutorial.com/basics/task-hello-world/#task-docker-images . Thank you for read me Alex , what do you think?

Comment: I haven't any issue to run concourse using a docker container to run my yml files but I would like install the binaries in a server with ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Carlos! Please update your question with file content, because it's hard to read yaml file in comments (indentation matters). And as message said -- seems that you do not have permissions to cd into /root

Comment: Also, look there: http://slack.concourse.ci; Concourse community is pretty good, so questions like that would be answered a lot more quickly than here.